# Selected test cases failing

Tags: java, recursion

This is my code for the problem

> Assume that the value of a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, ... , z = 26. You are
>   given a numeric string S.
>  Write a program to return the list of all
>   possible codes that can be generated from the given string.

```
import java.util.*;

public class solution {

    // Return a string array that contains all possible codes
    public static String[] getCode(String input){
        // Write your code here
        List<String> arrStr = new ArrayList<>();
        printAllPossibleCodes(input, "", arrStr);
        // for(String name: arrStr) {
        //     System.out.println(name);
        // }      
        String[] arr = new String[arrStr.size()];
        for(int j =0; j < arrStr.size(); j++){
          arr[j] = arrStr.get(j);
        }

        return arr; 
    }

    public static char getChar(int n){
        return (char) (n+96);
    }

    public static void printAllPossibleCodes(String input, String ans, List<String> arrStr){
        if(input.length() == 0){
            //System.out.println(ans);
            arrStr.add(ans);
            return;
        }

        int firstDigit = input.charAt(0) - '0';

        printAllPossibleCodes(input.substring(1), ans + getChar(firstDigit), arrStr);

        if(input.length() > 1){
            int firstTwoDigits = (input.charAt(0) - '0') * 10 + (input.charAt(1) - '0');
            if(firstTwoDigits >= 10 && firstTwoDigits <= 20){
                printAllPossibleCodes(input.substring(2), ans + getChar(firstTwoDigits), arrStr);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

I'm failing test cases for inputs "123" and "1123" while I'm passing the test for "35411". 
Where is my code going wrong?

Comment: You can pass a list into `printAllPossibleCodes` and add each item that you're printing.

Comment: I am not facing errors regarding the return type but I'm now failing a few test cases. I've edited the question too. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring `10 <= firstTwoDigits <= 20` in order to call `printAllPossibleCodes` recursively in the two-digit case. However, as there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, the requirement should be `10 <= firstTwoDigits <= 26`. Your first two test cases fail because they contain `"23"` as a substring, which is not between 10 and 20. However, the third test case contains no two-digit substring larger than 20 but less than 27 and thus does not have this issue.